# How to set default scroll option for full-screen mode in Mac Preview?

Tags: pdf, preview, file, defaults, macos

Mac Preview always opens in single page or double page view when going to full-screen mode while I prefer continuous scroll. I know I could press CMD+1 every time but is there a way to set this scroll option by default on PDF file open?

Edit: I also tried the Preferences -> Opening for the first time, Show as: Continuous scroll. It still always opens files in single page view when going to full-screen mode. Is this some sort of bug?

Version: OS X 10.9.4 MacBook Air

Answer (score 1):

Preview Preferences → Opening for the first time:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I already tried that -- it didn't work. I'll make the edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sierra, still the same problem. 
Went to prefs and changing the option (which I don't remember having changed before) with Terminal:

cd ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/
defaults write com.apple.Preview kPVPDFDefaultPageViewModeOption 0

and restarted Preview

Taken from http://www.amsys.co.uk/2013/08/how-to-configure-os-xs-preview-app-to-always-start-in-single-page-mode/

Didn't work, also not the option in the next post.... hm.

Answer (score 0):

Think I found it.
Used "defaults write com.apple.Preview PVPDFDisplayMode 3" from apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24359/…
It is making now scroll mode in fullscreen, works, now on OS 10.14

Answer (score -1):

The preview preferences may be overridden by system preferences. Open System Preferences, General.  In middle of panel there is a section that says 'Show scroll bars'. There are 3 options. I'd try the 'always' option and see if that works on preview. I'd leave the preview preference set to continuous scroll as well.